# Images in package Not visible

Tags: packages

I want to make a package where some variables are initialized to images. but when i save the package, all images are in the form of `ImageData` that are very long. how do i fix it ?

Comment: If the package works, there's nothing to be fixed.  Note that you can't store an image in a "visible" way in a plain text (`.m`) file.

Comment: Are you certain that the images are being stored in the package with head `ImageData`? I would have expected them to be stored with head `Image`, which is quite different (preserves the image metadata).

Comment: You can store as compressed strings and uncompress during an initialization.

Comment: Sorry it is stored as `Image`.A simple image is stored as follows                                     `Image[CompressedData["
1:eJxTTMoPSmNiYGAo5gASQYnljkVFiZXBLECOU2VJahJIShyI5YD4P33Av7//
cEv+BWHc8t+efMBl6r8PdlwsrAEv/v3FJvv/sfeCI3OZ3f5jkwXJA0E9w5f/
2K3++/vb/0zuXzhkgWA3Q9f/P9hN/vu5irkKh7VAPQcZNuPQCZLdx/DuDw6t
QPDrJS6dIB/d7XqJ08F//m9kOIfLUUDw49kvnHIEAW5jqQ0AKuOioA==
"], "Byte", ColorSpace -> "Grayscale", Interleaving -> None]`

Comment: Keep the images in an `Images` folder in your application's top directory and assign it to your variables by `Import`ing them. That might make for lot cleaner looking code.

Comment: i don't want to Import them, i'm making an Application to be run in a different location. i do not want to send my images along with it.

Comment: Then what do you want to do? What is your definition of "fixing it"?

Comment: But the data is properly interpreted when you work in the frontend and the package stylesheet. Try New->Package(.m). Anything else (e.g. workbench) will just show the textual representation.

Answer (score 1):

I´d recommend working in the frontend with the package stylesheet. You get all the fancy frontend features (typesetting, graphics...) but the file is maintained in package (.m) format.

All cells with the `Code` style will be carried over into the package (in fact they are initialization cells). Upon opening, the content is parsed and displayed as an ordinary notebook.

[image: Mathematica graphics]