# Symbolize Does Not Work in `.m` Files or What?

Tags: notebooks, symbols, boxes, save

I have a `.nb` (notebook) file which I should convert to a `.m` (mathematica package) file to run it remotely from command line of a high performance computing server. Before doing that I want to test whether my `.m` file runs correctly or not. (If I could run a `.nb` file using the command line then I didn't have all this trouble explained below!)

In my `.nb` file, I have used the `Symbolize` command for introducing the indexed symbols and I have used `Save` to get the output of the code in the format of a `.m` file. Everything works fine when I run the `.nb` file and the output is produced. Here is a simple code in a `.nb` file

[image]

Notice that the `Symbolize` is used from `Notation` palette and $x_1$ is entered as <kbd>x</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. But when this is converted to a `.m` file (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115197/running-mathematica-notebook-files-in-command-mode/115579#115579) for converting `.nb` to `.m`), it turns into

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["x", "i_"]]]
Subscript[x, 1] = 1;
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Save["OutPut.m", Subscript[x, 1]]
```

and after running the `.m` file I get this error

[image]

which means that $x_1$ is not a symbol. According to the following code, I conclude that `Symbolize` is not working in a `.m` file or there is some problem in the conversion of `.nb` to `.m`!

What should I do to fix this? Specifically, what should I do so that after converting `.nb` to `.m` such errors do not come up?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 7):

*This answer may seem slightly off but it was posted before recent updates. The bottom line holds though.*

It symbolizes boxes, not expressions, it is not `Subscript` which is now special but `SubscriptBox`.

You are supposed to use $x_1$ in your code but if you can't use `StandardForm`/2d typesetting then you have to make a round trip to boxes and back to expression:

```
roundtrip =  Function[expr
  , ToExpression@MakeBoxes[expr, StandardForm]
  , HoldFirst
];

roundtrip[ Subscript[x, 1] = 123 ]

roundtrip[ Save["OutPut.m", Subscript[x, 1]] ]
```

```
FilePrint@"OutPut.m"
```

[image]

Comment: @H.R. What I meant is: `SubscriptBox` is symbolized, not `Subscript`, and expecting `Subscript[_,_]` to be considered a symbol is wrong. Of course you can do `Subscript[x,1]=2` but this has nothing to do with `Symbolize`. It just creates downvalues for `Subscript` itself. p.s. you don't need GUI, you just need Mathematica and run `NotebookEvaluate @ path`, (`UsingFrontEnd` may be needed).

Comment: @H.R. Check out [this old post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19898/29). I once got it to work, but it is tricky and I have no time to check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59670/discussion-between-kuba-and-h-r).

Answer (score 4):

The Notation package relies on Box Form as used by the Front End.  Packages (generally) do not use Box Form therefore the Notation package does not work there.  If you start `WolframKernel.exe` and evaluate `` Get["Notation`"] `` you will see a variety of error messages starting with:

> FrontEndObject::notavail:     A front end is not available; certain
>   operations require a front end.

In translating from Box Form to plain text compromises have to be made as there is no direct equivalent for many things.

A Box Form subscript is normally translated as `Subscript` but this does not preserve the Symbol-like behavior enacted by the Notation package.  If you need Symbol-like behavior then a different compromise will need to be made.  One option is to replace the `Subscript` expression with a Symbol, which is what the Notation package is doing behind the scenes.  So your package code would look like:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

x⎵Subscript⎵1 = 1;

SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

Save["OutPut.m", x⎵Subscript⎵1]
```

(When the Notation package is loaded and subscripts are Symbolized this is the translation made by `ToString[expr, InputForm]`.)

If your package will be loaded from within the Front End then it is possible to load the Notation package.  Since packages are not written in Box Form we will need to manually apply [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) to our lines of code.  Your package might look like:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Needs["Notation`"]

Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["x", "i_"]]]

\(x\_1 = 1\) // ToExpression

\(Save[\("OutPut.m", x\_1\)]\) // ToExpression
```

This does work when loaded from a Notebook with [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html), producing a file:

> ```
> x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]1 = 1
> ```

Expressions may be converted into the shorthand box form (e.g. `\(x\_1 = 1\)`) using:

```
Function[, ToString[MakeBoxes @ #, InputForm], HoldAllComplete]
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the nice and detailed answer. I have lots of indexed symbols in my code and it is really annoying to change them one by one. Do you have any further suggestion or improvement according to this issue? :)

Comment: @H.R. I did not (yet) attempt an automated export solution.  Which format interests you?  (Assuming one does.)

Comment: I think your first solution (x⎵Subscript⎵1) which matches the default output format of mathemtica for indexed symbols is suitable. :)

Comment: @H.R. Okay, I shall see what I can do with that tomorrow.  (I am at the end of my day.)

Comment: I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Hi again. :) Did you figure out something for this?

Comment: @H.R. Sorry, frankly I wasn't in the mood to work on it the next day and then I forgot.  I'll try to come back to this but I'm a bit distracted these days which doesn't combine well with my inherent forgetfulness.

Comment: Ding! Ding! Reminder! :D

Comment: @H.R. People here work and spend their free time to help so please try to be more considerate. Usually such comment wouldn't seem wrong but you've called OP once and he told you that this is not the best time.

Comment: @Kuba: The last comment is about 10 days ago (June 5)! :) Anyway, I apologize if my comment caused any inconvenience. :)

Comment: *I have lots of indexed symbols in my code and it is really annoying to change them one by one.* Use `/.` or `Substitute` for that. You can also load the entire notebook's contents as a big expression, substitute on that, and write it out.